# Percentage chances on winning multiple prizes

Tags: php

I'm making a script that handles the percentage chances of winning when the user clicks a button. 
With the help of this topic [php - Chance of winning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332954/php-chance-of-winning). I used the following code:

```
function winningChance($percentage) {
    if($percentage < 1 || $percentage > 100) throw new Exception('Invalid percentage');
    global $result;
    if(rand(1, 100) <= $percentage) {
        $result = 'won';
    } else {
        $result = 'lost';
    }
    return $result;
}

echo "you have ".winningChance(50).'!';
```

Once this script has run, it registers the user name / last name / email and a field called `winner` with the `$result` in a SQL database

This works great, however I would like to handle multiple prizes with different percentages of winning chances.

Lets say prize1 have 20% chances of being won, 
prize2 30% chances 
and prize3 50% chances.
If I use `winningChance(20)`, `winningChance(30)`, `winningChance(50)` the user will have more chances of winning. How can I handle it so, the win/lost process happens in the same function for multiple prizes?

Comment: do you want to check for 20%, 30% and 50% simultaneously or randomly?

Comment: Why `global $result;`?

Comment: Im not sure I follow you on this. Is there a total chance of 100% to win? Or is it 1% chance to win, and if you win there is x0% of winning a certain prize?

Comment: @YatinTrivedi basicaly i would like to check simultaneously for the 3 prices one having 20% chances the other 30% and the last 50%

Comment: @jackflash i made $result a global var because i need it outiside of the function to register the result in the database

Comment: You don't: `$result = winningChance(50);`

Comment: @Shomz great thanks i will clean up that part.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<strike>If I understood correctly, you want to have multiple winning calculations for each user at the same time, independent of one another. There are numerous ways to do this. Modify your function so that you can pass an associative array as an argument, for example.</strike>

The array would be a map of price=>percentage values and then you do the calculations for each pair.
You'd also need to modify your result variable in an array, and on each pass just push the result of the calculation into it. You can also use an associative array here to show price=>won/lost. After you looped through all the pairs and filled up the result variable with the results, just return the variable.

Based on your last comment, this is what you need:

```
function winningChance($percentage) {
    foreach($percentage as $p) {
        if($p < 1 || $p > 100) 
            throw new Exception('Invalid percentage');
    }
    if (count($percentage) != 3)
        throw new Exception('Three prizes need to be defined');

    $rand = rand(1, 100); // generate the random chance only once!

    if ($rand <= $percentage[0])
        $result = 'won first prize';
    elseif ($rand <= $percentage[1])
        $result = 'won second prize';
    elseif ($rand <= $percentage[2])
        $result = 'won third prize';
    else
        $result = 'lost';

    return $result;
}
```

And call the function like this:

```
//the array contains probability percentages for the first, second and third place respectively
$res = winningChance( array(20, 30, 50) );
echo "You have $res!";
// write $res to the db here
```

Comment: it's quiet hard to explain correctly as English isn't my mother thong. but basically the calculation should append at the same time (when the user submit his name/last name/mail) and only one of the 3 prices should be won, each with their own percentage chances.

Comment: Go ahead and try, give us an example scenario.

Comment: @LorenzoPirondini Try this.

Comment: @shmoz it works well thank's i just had to add return $result; after the last else if in order to output the result on echo.

Comment: Hmm, the one return I put in the function is enough for all cases. Seems like you've confused the result in the function and the one outside of it - I've updated my answer to show you the difference ($result vs $res)

Comment: @shmoz actualy the "return" probleme was from your older response, my comment crossed with your edit. i just used the last edit you made, it works great with the random chance thrown only once, on the other case the win seemed to happened to often. thanks for your help.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Your method gives 20% chance of winning first prize, 10% chance for second prize and 20% chance for third.

Comment: @deacs  The question wasn't clear, see the edits and this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359383/percentage-chances-on-winning-multiple-prizes/19359683?noredirect=1#comment28684982_19359383. What my answer means is this: 20% chance for 1st, 30% chance for 2nd or better (2nd or 1st) and 50% chance for 3rd or better (3rd, 2nd or 1st).

Comment: @Shomz based on the question and that comment,I highly doubt thats how OP wanted to use this method. On average, only 10% of his users will have won second prize, 20% first, 20% third, 50% will have lost.

Comment: @deacs We can guess all day. OP had a concept of a loss (as you can see in their code), so this diversifies the winners into three possible prizes. Also, OP had accepted this answer, so there's no point in guessing further.

Comment: @Shomz having more chance of getting first prize than second prize doesn't sound logical at all, so I'm assuming OP is mistaken by accepting this answer. Just pointing that out for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the chance of winning depends on the price.

```
function getChanceOfWinning($price)
{
  $chances = array(
    10 => 20,
    20 => 30,
    30 => 50
  );
  if (isset($chances[$price])) {
    return $chances[$price];
  }
  return 0; // <-- default chance
}

function calculateWinningChance($price)
{
  $chance = getChanceOfWinning($price);
  $calc   = rand(1, 100);

  if ($calc <= $chance) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function calculateWinningChances(array $prices)
{
  $results = array();
  foreach($prices as $price) {
    $results[$price] = calculateWinningChance($price);
  }
  return $results;
}

var_dump(calculateWinningChances(array(10,20, 30,40,700)));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution ?

```
function roll( $iChance ) {
        $iCursor = rand( 0,99 );
        $aModel = array();
        while ( count( $aModel ) != $iChance ) {
            $iRandValue = rand( 0,99 );
            if ( !in_array( $iRandValue, $aModel ) ) {
                $aModel[] = $iRandValue;
            }
        }
        return in_array( $iCursor, $aModel );
    }
```

Edit: More perfomance:

```
function roll( $iChance ) {
    $iChance = ceil( ( $iChance > 100 ) ? 100 : (int)$iChance);
    $iCursor = rand( 0, 99 );
    $aModel = range( 0, 99 );
    shuffle( $aModel );
    return in_array( $iCursor, array_slice( $aModel, 0, $iChance ) );
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer, is it more accurate than making nested if statements? could you please explain a little bit the code? thanks

Comment: I changed the function to achieve better performance and greater readability logic.

Answer (score -1):

tweak your function code like,

```
instead of,

if(rand(1, 100) <= $percentage) {
    $result = 'won';
} else {
    $result = 'lost';
}
```

to,

```
if(rand(1, 100) >= 50) {
    $result = 'won third price';
} else if(rand(1, 100) >= 30) {
    $result = 'won second price';
}
else if(rand(1, 100) >= 20) {
    $result = 'won first price';
}
else
{
    $result='lost';
}
```

Comment: yeah that's quiet good, but in therms of exact chances, the usre have first 50% chances of winning the third price then 30% of winning the 2nd and then 20% of winning the 1st price, which makes im have less than 20% chances of winning the 1st price, is that correct or am i missing something?

Comment: write your exact required case here with example